# Firebase iOS Crashlytics crashes not being reported in Flutter, but Android is working

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

The error message is as follows：

> ======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =
> The following message was thrown:
> 测试第一次上传ios1111
>
> ===================================================================================================
> 10.20.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Submitted an on-demand exception, starting delay 6.00000000000000000000
> 10.20.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Crashlytics skipped rotating the Install ID during urgent mode because it is run on the main thread, which can't succeed. This can happen if the app crashed the last run and Crashlytics is uploading urgently.

Here are my dependencies:

```
firebase_core: ^2.23.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.5
firebase_analytics: ^10.8.4`
```

podfile:

```
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
pod 'FirebaseCore'`
```

flutter:

[image: flutter]

[image: nothing]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run in release mode ,it's ok